# Edit single Image with CSS. The Img Src with a class is still changing all images on website

Tags: html, css, image

I have an image that i need to edit with CSS so it becomes mobile responsive.

I have added a class to the image, but when I edit that class with CSS all my images change to these settings?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please create a snippet, codepen or jsfiddle of your code? @Vivid_Graphic_Group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing code it would be hard to answer, but the more SPECIFIC you can be when targeting elements, the better! Here are 2 ways:

**CSS NESTED CLASSES**

Two classes separated by a *space* targets **only** the elements nested inside another. Example:

```
.myParentClass .myNestedClass {
       property: value;
    }
```

```
<div class="myParentClass">
     <img class="myNestedClass" src="./myPicture"/>
</div>
```

**CSS COMBINED CLASSES**

Two classes without **ANY** space between them means that the CSS rules will **ONLY** apply if the element contains **BOTH** classes. This will certainly make your element even more unique! For example:

```
.myCoolClass.myMoreSpecificClass {
       property: value;
    }
```

```
 <div>          
     <p class="myCoolClass myMoreSpecificClass"> Hello </p>
 </div>
```

I would recommend you to use the second option to target only that single picture. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

**Use bootstrap class for responsive image. you can use your personal css for image width and height and for other styles.... here your solve**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>image problem</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>This is image</h1>
    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/02/04/09/50/the-alps-4817766_960_720.jpg" alt="nature">
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```