# is it possible to edit a element inside a class in js / jsx how u can in css?

Tags: reactjs

I need to edit the css of some images in a class, but I'm doing it in a function, I've already done something similar but it directly edits a class, I need to know if I can do the same but edit only the img element of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone has had a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60124637/edit-single-image-with-css-the-img-src-with-a-class-is-still-changing-all-image). I believe the solution is to use nested classes:

```
<div class="myParentClass">
     <img class="myNestedClass" src="./myPicture"/>
</div>
```

Then just edit the class as you would normally. If you want to add css to it, you can just use:

```
.myParentClass .myNestedClass {
       property: value;
    }
```